# Input array field adding single quotes when console log in express js (node js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

I have a form with some input field and also have a array input field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="test[0][name]" value="car" />
<input type="text" name="test[1][value]" value="100" />
```

I am posting this form via ajax.
Now when I console log post data into express js. I am getting like below :

```
{
 user_id : '1',
'test[0]' : 'a',
'test[1]' : 'b',
}
```

So issues are :

1) Why I am getting input array like this ? Instead I should get array as object in express js.

2) I am able to access user_id using `post.user_id` but can not access test array.

I am trying to access test array using `post.test` and `post.test.name` but getting undefined always.

My ajax code is :

```
$("#frmSave").on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var el = $("#btnPublish");

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image",$("#image").get(0).files[0]);

            var other_data = $("#frmSave").serializeArray();
            $.each(other_data, function(key, input) {
                formData.append(input.name, input.value);
            })

            $.ajax({
                url : "{{ admin_url }}offer/add",
                type : "POST",
                data : formData,
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                beforeSend : function() {
                    el.html('<img src="{{ admin_url }}images/loaders/loader5.gif" width="15"> Wait...');
                },
                success : function(json) {
                    if(json.errors) {
                        var errors_string = '';
                        $.each(json.errors, function(index,value) {
                            errors_string += value + '<br />';
                        });

                        if(errors_string != '') {
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: 'Required Field',
                                text: errors_string,
                                class_name: 'growl-danger',
                                sticky: false,
                                time: '2000'
                            }); 
                        }
                    } else if(json.error_msg) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: 'Error!',
                            text: json.error_msg,
                            class_name: 'growl-danger',
                            sticky: false,
                            time: '2000'
                        }); 
                    } else if(json.success_msg) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: json.success_msg,
                            class_name: 'growl-success',
                            sticky: false,
                            time: '2000'
                        });
                    }
                    el.html('<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> &nbsp; Publish');
                },
                error(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     $.gritter.add({
                         title: 'Something went wrong',
                         text: xhr.status + ':' + thrownError,
                         class_name: 'growl-warning',
                         sticky: false,
                         time: '2000'
                     });
                     el.html('<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> &nbsp; Publish');
                }
            })
        });
```

So can anyone help me out ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)? If so, check if you have [extended](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended) as `true` in the `urlencoded` options.

Comment: I made this true "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));" and I am using formidable module to access post data.

Comment: I've never used formidable, so if my previous comment didn't make it work, I can't help you. sry

Comment: @FirstOne No, I tried as per your comment but nothing worked. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access using

```
post['test[0]']
```

Maybe you could post more code and we could help you better.

Regards!

Roth

Comment: Yes I am able to access like this but why I am getting input array like this. Instead I should get array as object.